# how to debug a css issue in iphone 5 (ui issues)?

Tags: css, iphone-5

I want to know how to debug a css issue in iphone 5.

I tried it using firelite plugin. But on rotating from portrait to landscape the firelite is occupying the whole screen.

Is there any other way of debugging css issue in iphone 5?

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html):

> With Safari on iOS 6 and later, you can debug your mobile web content
>   from your Mac. You can view JavaScript errors, edit HTML attributes,
>   change CSS properties, and more—just as you would when developing for
>   Safari on OS X. This chapter describes how to use Web Inspector to
>   debug web content on iOS.
>
> You should test your web content on both the desktop and various iOS
>   devices. If you do not have iOS devices for testing, you can use iOS
>   Simulator in the iOS SDK. Because there is a difference between web
>   browsing on iOS and OS X, you should specifically test your content on
>   iPhone and iPad or emulate the hardware device in Simulator. When
>   testing in Safari on any platform, you can use Web Inspector to debug
>   your web content.
>
> For more tips on debugging web content in Safari, read [Safari
>   Developer Tools Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874). Read the section “[Changing the User Agent
>   String](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/PrototypingYourWebsite/PrototypingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH7-SW11)” in Safari Developer Tools Guide to learn how to simulate
>   iPhone- and iPad-like behavior in Safari on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Adobe Edge Ispect.
If you install the app on your iPhone, and the plugin in Chrome you can debug your website using the Chrome dev tools.

More info: http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/